# how to fix rendering problems on android studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-theme

ok i have tried everything i can fix it but each time i change the theme i always get a rendering error can some pls help me

[image: this is what it looks like]

Rendering Problems Missing styles. Is the correct theme chosen for this layout?  Use the Theme combo box above the layout to choose a different layout, or fix the theme style references.  NOTE: One or more layouts are missing the layout_width or layout_height attributes. These are required in most layouts.

Comment: Post your layout file, please.

Comment: Without more details it's unlikely anyone can answer this question.

Comment: I fix it thanks a lot but not it just says the name of its working now but the activity is showing the name of my app not the name of that particular activity how do I fix that??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explicitly stated in your error log, you have to set `layout_width` and `layout_height` attributes to all layouts in all your `xml` files.

In other words, your layout file should contain something like this inside its tags.

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

You should set it to `wrap_content` or `match_parent` according to the way it want to be,

Comment: I know but both are on "match parent" what should I change it to

Comment: @Anthony edit your post and add yout layout file.

Comment: I fix it thanks a lot but not it just says the name of my app not the name of that particular activity how do I fix that